# Java, How to include PNG images in Jar?

Tags: java, jar, ioexception

Currently, I am doing image loading from:

fi.xman3.assets. ( src/fi/xman3/assets/ )

With this code:

```
public static BufferedImage get(String path) {
    BufferedImage img = null;

    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return img;
}
```

When I try to run the JAR file from cmd ( java -jar example.jar ), it just starts giving me IOException errors for "File doesn't exist".

Running from Eclipse works without any errors.

Comment: If it is packed into a jar it is no longer considered a `File` but a `resource`. You need to go about doing something like this..                                  `URL imageURL = this.getClass().getResource("/fi/xman3/assets/image.png");`    then do..  `ImageIcon t = new ImageIcon(imageURL);`

Comment: @3kings you should turn that into an answer so it can be accepted and upvoted. :)

Comment: 3kings, that doesn't seem to be working. Now I get an error saying "Cannot use this in a static context", when I highlight "this".

Comment: Alright, I did some fiddling and "ImageLoader.class.getResource(path);" seems to work. Thanks!